# Ubuntu 22.04: 'Temporary failure in name resolution' for local network

Tags: 22.04, dns, virtualization, hostname

I am setting up a VM with Ubuntu 22.04.

I´m having problems with resolving hostnames of my local network. I can ping other Servers by IP, but not by hostname: 'Temporary failure in name resolution'.

However, i can ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

I entered my local DNS-Server(s) into /etc/resolve/resolv.conf and into my /etc/netplan/01.netcfg.yaml

Do i need to enter it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to install `libnss-mdns` and configure `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to use `mdns4_minimal`.

Ubuntu Server does not come with configured `mdns` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I solved my problem with

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 system.  The system repeatedly lost most internet connection after a couple of hours.  A few apps can still access the internet and I can still access a few web pages using their IP address.  The problem can be solved with a reboot.

To tackle this annoying problem, I tested `nfw disable`, `netplan try`, `dhclient -r`,`ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`, `systemctl enable NetworkManager`, as well as several other suggestions that require modifying files such as  `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`, none of these methods works.

I can ping my DNS server, but if I ping an actual webpage, I get the error "Temporary failure in name resolution". `resolvectl query` would lead to the error "resolve call failed: Connection timed out."

Using the command at the beginning, I was able to restore my internet connection without rebooting the system.

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that Cisco AnyConnect causes the problem. The same problem repeats almost every time after I disconnect the VPN.  I am still not sure why this happens, but the original commend can temporarily fix the problem.